# How to check the client connected to which node in the cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0, datastax

We want to check the client connections going to which server in the cluster. Is there any way to track it?

I saw some audit logs which has host files and source files.

host:FQDN/5.6.7.8|source:/1.2.3.4

Is this means the client from 1.2.3.4 ipaddress is connected to server 5.6.7.8 to run the query?

5.6.7.8 is the coordinator node here for this session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

indeed. Your assumption is totally correct. When you take a look at the "CQL Logging examples" part in the Datastax' Cassandra documentation: 
http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.0/security/data_auditing

It explains that in your example 5.6.7.8 is the Cassandra node coordinating the requests from the client with IP 1.2.3.4.